# Не работают исключение в gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Пытаюсь настроить gitignore чтобы картинка профиля по дефолту могла загружаться в гит и любой, кто стянет себе проект, тоже мог спокойной загружать картинку не парясь, но беда в том, что как бы я не пробовал сделать исключения картинки, все напрасно.
Вот примерно так выглядит путь от проекта к картинке с учетом гитигнора:

```
/project/
 -/media/
 --/avatars/(Не должно идти на гит, а должно остаться только на компе)
 --default_profile_image.jpg
 -.gitignore
```

media/*
!media/default_profile_image.jpg
не помогает и примерные аналоги такого исключения тоже.

Comment: не понятно, чего именно вы хотите добиться. уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дире **avatars** создайте файл *.gitignore*

```
*
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже сам разобрался